# C# Textbox starts on second line after pressing Enter

Tags: c#, textbox

After my textbox clears. The start position starts at second line instead of the first. (I'm not sure what's the flashing | is called)

I'm making a chat server so there is a button to send the current text. And on keypress Enter it will activate button1 so as to send the current text.

TextChanged event is just purely for debugging purposes.

textChanged is called twice. Once on inBox.Text = string.Empty; This part is still fine. inBox.Text is null.

After exiting from button1_Click, TextChanged is called for the second time. But this time. the start position is on the second line instead of the first.
The length of inBox.Text is now 2.

Any idea what's the problem? Thanks.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Global.Send("{Chat}{" + Global.userName + "}" + inBox.Text);
            inBox.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void inBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
                button1.PerformClick();
        }

        void InBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            char[] c = tb.Text.ToCharArray();
            int len = c.Length;
        }
```

Comment: Incidentally, that flashing I is called the "Insertion Point", "Caret", or "I-Beam" amongst other names.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28computers%29

Comment: I initially thought that it was called Caret too. From the method "TextBox.ScrollToCaret" But the Wiki for Caret gave another definition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It is called the caret. See [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648398%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Inbox_Keypressed() method, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property to true <strike>(also, you shouldn't use `13` - `Keys.Return` is more readable)</strike>:

```
private void inBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyChar == 13)
  {
    button1.PerformClick();
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for Handled.  But Keys.Return isn't kosher, it is a virtual key.  The cast is the reminder that there's a mismatch.  Use '\r' instead.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for the info on Keys.Return. I'm actually more of a Delphi guy than C#. :) Corrected.

Comment: KeyUp doesn't work, you are now sending the '\r' along with the text.  Setting e.Handled to true prevents the keystroke from being added to the text.

Comment: @Hans good call on the KeyUp still sending the "\r" - I didn't think about that, I agree this way is better.

Answer (score 1):

Set multiline property to false?

Comment: Try using WLM on single line?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the keypress event fires before the key is sent to the textbox.  That is, your code executes, and then a KeyChar 13 is sent to the textbox after.

Try using KeyUp instead.